# Алгоритм умножения элементов массива

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, turbopascal

> Вычислить произведение чисел, больших заданного D и стоящих на местах, кратных 3; Подсчитать кол-во чисел, не равных заданному X.

Всё бы понятно, вот код:

```
program dv5;
var
    c:array[1..100] of real;
    i,n,k:integer;
    f,d,x:real;
begin
    writeln ('vvedite dlinnu massiva');
    readln (n);
    f:=0;
    k:=0;
    d:=0;
    x:=0;
    writeln ('vvedite el massiva');
    for i:=1 to n do
        readln (c[i]);
    writeln ('vvedite D');
    readln (d);
    writeln ('vvedite x');
    readln (x);
    for i:=1 to n do
    begin
        if (c[i]>d) and (i mod 3=0)
        then
            f:=f*c[i];
        if (c[i]<>x)
        then
            k:=k+1;
    end;
    writeln ('proizvedenie 4isel>d kratn3= ',f:5:2);
    writeln ('kol-vo 4isel ne ravnyh x= ',k);
    readln
end.
```

но при выводе произведения пишет 0:0.  никак не могу понять в чём проблема.
вот мои данные по которым я составляю:

длинна массива = 12
элементы 0 1 8 2 5 8 3 1 7 1 2 5
D=7
X=3
в ответе должно быть:
произведение= 64
числа не равные x=11
числа не равные выводит, а произведение пишет 0:0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Беда в том, что начальное значение f нулевое. Однако если просто изменить его на 1, то придётся ещё проверять, что нужные числа вообще есть. Можно использовать такой вариант:

```
  f := 0;  {это оставляем}
  ....
  if (c[i]>d) and (i mod 3=0) then
     if f = 0 then
         f := c[i];
     else
         f := f*c[i];
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь всё заработало